# Portal app URLs are wrong

Tags: arcgis-portal

We have portal setup at a URL similar to the following through a reverse proxy:

```
http://<portal url>/arcgis/home
```

The WebContextURL parameter is set to this:

```
https://<portal url>/arcgis
```

Almost everything is working as it should. The only problem we are having now is when we try to create a an App using a template. The app creates fine but the resulting registered url is wrong. The URL ends up being something like this which returns a 404 when you try to go to it

```
http://<portal url>/app/...
```

If you change the app URL to this then the app loads:

```
http://<portal url>/arcgis/app/...
```

Why isn't it doing this from the get go? Can I change this behavior some where? I haven't found a spot to change this.

Comment: In the Portal classes I've taken, it was stressed that multiple Web Adaptors were necessary (two on Server, and one on Portal).  If you're not using WA, then you'll need to replicate the functionality.  If you are, then you'll need to tell us how many installs, and how the mappings have been configured.  Given the security issues raised, you might be better off contacting Esri Tech Support to deal with this directly.

Comment: Yes, we have three Web Adaptors now, each on a separate host (sub-domain). One is for Portal, one is for the hosted ArcGIS Server and the final one is for the production ArcGIS Server. Ya, probably have to get Tech Support on this one but alway hopeful to get an answer before diving into that morass.

Comment: You should have *two* on the hosted AGS instance, and likely two on the production server as well.

Comment: So I got a message back from an ESRI employee on GeoNet and this is apparently a known issue with Portal 10.3.1 and will be fixed in 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

According to ESRI this is a known issue in Portal 10.3.1 and will be fixed in 10.4.

Comment: Adding a link to the GeoNet thread and including a brief quote from it would turn this into an answer of adequate length.